# Url problem due to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I uploaded my website [here](http://www.kantoorleenknegt.be) . But when I check the url it doesn't change when I click another page. I used the Rewritebase in my .htaccess to have clean urls. The url should be like kantoorleenknegt.be/contact ....

Comment: You don't need RewriteBase to generate clean URLs. That's purely used if the site is running in a virtual document root. It's worth noting that your site isn't redirecting. Also, can you post the relevant directives? You should be able to do this with the default Drupal .htaccess file unless you're making significant changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a drupal question. You are seen the website through a frame 
The real url is `http://31.186.174.215/~leenkneg/` where the urls work as expected.

To answer your question after the info you gave.
One solution is to add an A record to the DNS of the domain. So every http traffic will land to your site but without the users notice and the can have the emails where they want.

So you will have the hosting and the can keep the emails.

Comment: So the problem lays with my domainname?

Comment: You have a domain name (kantoorleenknegt.be) that have an index page with just a frame that show the real location of your site(/~leenkneg/). If you move your site from the /~leenkneg/ to the targeted domain it should work just fine!

Comment: the domain name kantoorleenknegt.be is redirected to http://31.186.174.215/~leenkneg/

Comment: How you have done the migration?

Comment: I don't have the ownership of the domain name. I juste designed the page and gave the url http://31.186.174.215/~leenkneg/ so the domain is linked to the ftp where the site is.

Comment: I think the professional think to do is to tell them to give you access to the ftp.domain.de so you can upload the site and after that you have to create the database.Import from the one you have now and change the settings.php to reflect the new db.

Comment: that is not possible because i'm in charge of the hosting. they only have the domain because of the mailboxes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I contacted my provider, the problem wasn't on my server but on the domain name, they used an iframe to redirect the page. They had to change te dns and normally it should work.

Comment: i'm glad it finally worked!